# rails 4 model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm new to rails and I'm a little confused about model associations.
here is a brief description of what need to do. 
I have a `User` model, that `has_many project`, and `Project` `has_many upload`, `Upload` `belongs_to project` and `Project` `belongs_to user`.

So far it's working, users can access there projects, and from that project access there uploads. 
the thing is, any user can have access to every users projects and uploads. by changing the url localhost:3000/projects/9/uploads/57 
I need to make the projects and uploads only accessible by the correct user ( the user how has created the projects and uploads )

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "projects", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "comment"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "uploads", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "project_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "edl_file_name"
  t.string   "edl_content_type"
  t.integer  "edl_file_size"
  t.datetime "edl_updated_at"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.string   "remember_token"
end
```

**User Model**

```
 has_many :project
 has_many :upload, :through => project
```

**Project Model**

```
belongs_to :user 
has_many :upload, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Upload Model**

```
belongs_to :project
has_one :user, :through => :project
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users  

resources :projects do
 resources :uploads do 
 end
end
```

Relationship maybe? How would you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

```
User Model
  has_many :uploads
  has_many :projects, :through => uploads

Project Model
  has_many :uploads
  has_many :users, :through => uploads # Maybe :dependent => :destroy

Upload Model # Just 2 foreign keys here
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
```

Basically both Project and User are using the join table 'uploads' to access information about the other entity.  Join tables used in this fashion have 2 `belongs_to`'s and then the references tables have the `has_many` `:through ->`'s.

More at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to a model that `has_many`, the referenced object becomes pluralized. So it should be `has_many :projects`. The same with the uploads; it should be `has_many :uploads`. When you association the other side of the relationship (`belongs_to`), you are correct where it is singular.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your has_many relations, your declaration of the target model was only in singular form.

For your User model, you should do the following:

```
    has_many :projects
    has_many :uploads, :through => project
```

Rails takes in the plural forms of the target model when using the has_many relation.  Just check your other relations for pluralization errors, and you should be fine.